# count sales with window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT CustomerID,COUNT(*) AS CountOfSales,
COUNT(CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY CountOfSales) Total,

RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS Ranking,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC) AS Row,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*)) AS DenseRanking
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

and that gives this result:

```
CustomerID  CountOfSales    Total   Ranking Row DenseRanking
11091   28  1   1   2   17
11176   28  1   1   1   17
11200   27  1   3   9   16
11331   27  1   3   12  16
11287   27  1   3   5   16
11262   27  1   3   8   16
11276   27  1   3   11  16
11330   27  1   3   6   16
11711   27  1   3   13  16
11277   27  1   3   3   16
```

But now I want to have a column like total countOfSales, so: there are 2 with 28 and 11 with 27

so my question is how to manage that?

Thank you

Comment: Does MySQL really support those windows functions?

Comment: what's the logic behind 11 with 27 because there are 9 records only with id 27

Comment: it is just a part of the result of the query

Comment: Your question does not make any sense... as you asking for a sum by Id? COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY Id)

Comment: Just want to have a total of CountOfsales. It is very clear what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could wrap your query into a sub query and do a COUNT(*) with PARTITION BY:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CountOfSales) AS total_countOfSales
FROM (
SELECT CustomerID,COUNT(*) AS CountOfSales,
COUNT(CustomerID) OVER (PARTITION BY CountOfSales) Total,

RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS Ranking,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC) AS Row,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*)) AS DenseRanking
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID
) a
```